# How to scan allowed outbound (destination) ports on the local host?

Tags: network, penetration-test, network-scanners

Without access to firewall rules, I want to scan allowed outbound (destination) ports on the local machine.

I would take too long to start a netcat listener for each of the destination ports on a remote host, to connect to, for testing.

Is there a smarter way, preferably using Bash scripting?

Answer (score 3):

If you just care which ports are allowed as outgoing target on your machine just do a packet capture at the remote host to see which packets from your client reach the remote host. There does not need to be a listener there in order for the packet to arrive at the host, it only needs a listener in order to respond to the packet.

Comment: Thank you. So, you would run `tcpdump` or `Wireshark` on the remote host?

Comment: @Shuzheng: yes, any of these will do. For automatic analysis (i.e. process the output with some script) a command line based client like tcpdump or tshark is probably preferable.

Comment: Doesn't the network card need to be put into some special mode in order for `tcpdump` to see the packets?

Comment: @Shuzheng: you probably mean promiscuous mode - this is only needed to capture all packets arriving at the network card including packets not destined for this specific target. This is not needed here.

Comment: Indeed. I like your answer. If no better answer comes in near future, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You could run nmap on the local host and setup a nc listener on a remote host.

On the remote host you could use something along these lines:

for i in `seq 1 65000`; do nc -l $i &; sleep 1; done

Depending on how beefy the remote host is I’d be careful around the sleep section. The sleep is there to prevent it from spawning an excessive number of netcat processes at once.

On the local host run the following:

nmap -p- -PN

Then just wait for the results.

Comment: Wouldn't `nmap` check the ports much faster than `nc` process them, i.e. lots of false positives would be reported?
What if `nmap` isn't available on the local host?

Comment: Nc is soley there to be a listener the other side of the firewall. It is still nmap that is doing the scanning. Netcat is just there to confirm that nmap can communicate via that port through the firewall. You can get nmap on any OS pretty much.

Comment: Note that the proposed script would take like 65000 (~18 hours) seconds to complete.

Comment: ^^^ What they said

Comment: @NonStandardModel - Indeed, this would be a problem. Still, if I let `nmap` run without the 1 second delay, then `nmap` would scan all 65535 ports before `nc` would have a chance for listening on them.

Comment: @Shuzheng its nc that has the delay just so it doesnt open up all 65535 ports at the same time, you could remove or change the command slightly to suit better.

Comment: @NonStandardModel - But, `nmap -p- PN` runs very fast. However, the `nc` listeners start over a long period of time.

Comment: Also..running nmap on localhost will give you all the ports. Than you can insert just a list of those ports into the nc script.